# SQL Server Steps For Changing US Date to UK Date (ymd to dmy)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Can anyone help me what steps should I take to have my SQL Server show date query as `dd-mm-yyyy`?

Right now clicking on table select top 1000 rows it will show the dates as `yyyy-mm-dd 2013-01-01` my sql server set as English. Should I change the Server default Language to British English? I have changed the server + the user to British English but when I execute sql query

```
SELECT TOP 1000 [id_objednavk]
      ,[datumprevzeti_objednavk]
      ,[id_prod]
      ,[mnozstvi_objednavk]
      ,[stavzbozi_objednavk]
  FROM [DAR].[dbo].[Objednavky_dodavat]
```

The date is shown as `2013-01-01`

Can anyone help?

Comment: `yyyy-mm-dd` is ISO standard not US.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the `Advanced` option of a database `Properties` and change the option to British English.

Alternatively:

> SET DATEFORMAT dmy;

[SET DATEFORMAT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189491.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Use [date and time styles with CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) to change how the value is displayed:

```
DECLARE @date DATETIME = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
-- yyyy-mm-dd
SELECT @date;
-- dd/mm/yyyy
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, @date, 103);
```

Returns

```
11/12/2013
```

Formatting date and time is a job for the presentation layer. [SET LANGUAGE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174398.aspx) and [SET DATEFORMAT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189491.aspx) will not change how the date is displayed in an SSMS results window.